# How can I fix sfdx error: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, sfdc

**I am getting this error when I try to deploy source to Org **

```
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
```

[image]

**sfdx-project.json**

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "48.0"
}
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Could you add which file you're trying to send and the full project tree ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in VS Code / SFDX and stumbled onto this question.  I eventually figured out the issue, so thought I'd share my solution here.

I was getting this error when doing one of the Trailhead modules that had me copy the [ldsUtils](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsUtils) component into my `lwc` folder.  What I mistakenly did was copy the `ldsUtils.js` file directly into `lwc` instead of nesting it within an `ldsUtils` folder.  This was resulting in the same error as you mention.  Once I moved the `ldsUtils.js` file into the `ldsUtils` folder (along with `ldsUtils.js-meta.xml`), the problem was fixed.